# Set RadioButton-ToggleGroup-with Listener to null when user pushes Clear button

Tags: javafx, listener

I have 2 `RadioButton`s in a `ToggleGroup` with a listener. After a `RadioButton` is selected and data recorded, user is to click a clear button to reset the screen. When clear button is clicked, I want the `RadioButton`s to be unselected, which I thought would mean I would set the `ToggleGroup` property to null. But the null value throws a `NullPointerException` because of the listener.
I tried to remove the listener when the clear button is clicked, which would then be added back when the `RadioButton` is selected, but could not get the `removeListener` statement formatted correctly.
I have added a try-catch around the statement that reads the radio button value, which eliminates the red ink error message, but doesn't seem very elegant.

```java
public class ClearToggle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        RadioButton rbGo = new RadioButton("Go");
        RadioButton rbStop = new RadioButton("Stop");
        
        Label lGoStop = new Label("");
        
        Button clear = new Button("Clear");
        
        VBox vbox1 = new VBox(rbGo, rbStop);
        
        ToggleGroup tGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        rbGo.setToggleGroup(tGroup);
        rbStop.setToggleGroup(tGroup);
        
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.getChildren().addAll(vbox1, lGoStop, clear);
        grid.setHgap(30);
        grid.setConstraints(vbox1, 0, 0);
        grid.setConstraints(lGoStop, 1, 0);
        grid.setConstraints(clear, 0, 1);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        tGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ob,Toggle o, Toggle n) { 
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)tGroup.getSelectedToggle();
                
                try {
                    lGoStop.setText(rb.getText());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                }
            }
        });
        
        clear.setOnAction(e -> {
            lGoStop.setText("");
            tGroup.selectToggle(null);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your listener, what do you expect newValue to be if you null the group's selectedToggle ;) In other words: your listener is wrong in not coping with null, check newValue for null and only let it do stuff when available. Then you can get rid off the incorrect (in two aspects: never silently swallow caught exception, never use exception handling for normal behavior) try/catch block. Also don't access the group's for its selected toggle, the notification already carries it.

Comment: @Abra having no selectedToggle is valid state, as is using public api `group.selectToggle(null)` to get there :)

Comment: Just do a null check, instead of squashing the null pointer exception. (You can also use instanceof, because `n instanceof RadioButton` will be false if `n` is null. I.e. in the latest version of Java you can do `if (n instanceof RadioButton rb) lGoStop.setText(rb.getText());`)

Comment: Got it!  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I have come up with an interesting alternative.  If you add another RadioButton, one more than you need, when you click a button to clear the screen and reset the controls, you can select the extra RadioButton.  It still triggers the listener, but you are not setting ToggleGroup to null, which throws NullPointerException.  To make the extra RadioButton not appear on the screen, use rbX.setVisible(false);
I am curious... does this approach break any coding conventions?
Here is the code.

```
public class Test_Clear_ToggleGroup extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        RadioButton rbA = new RadioButton("A");
        RadioButton rbB = new RadioButton("B");
        RadioButton rbX = new RadioButton("X"); // the extra RadioButton
        rbX.setVisible(false);
        VBox v = new VBox(rbA, rbB, rbX);
        v.setSpacing(5);
        v.setLayoutX(75);
        v.setLayoutY(75);
        
        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
        rbA.setToggleGroup(tg);
        rbB.setToggleGroup(tg);
        rbX.setToggleGroup(tg);
        
        Button playAgain = new Button("Play Again");
        playAgain.setLayoutX(75);
        playAgain.setLayoutY(200);
        
        Pane p = new Pane(v, playAgain);
        Scene s = new Scene(p, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        tg.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(e -> {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)tg.getSelectedToggle();
            // Print to console when a rb is pushed
            System.out.println("Value of rb.getText(): " + rb.getText());  
        });
        
        playAgain.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("Play Again was clicked"); 
            // Set toggle selection to rbX (the rb that is setVisible(false)
            rbX.setSelected(true);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a dirty hack which is completely unneeded - the clean solution is outlined in the comments to the question

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual layout (like hard-coding the location of nodes), instead use a suitable layout pane.